# cmd, Open file in Command Prompt shell without knowing its extension

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, explorer

I would like to run a file, in cmd without knowing the type (e.g. JPG, mp3, txt, mp4 and etc).
I tried to use 'start' command, but start (as far I found) need to know the full name of the file (with extension) and which program it should use to run it (e.g. VLC, notepad, photo viewer).
So, for example, instead of using `C:\AI>start "VLC media player" "Bernard.avi"` I want something like `C:\AI>start "Bernard"` to work similar.

Comment: Why don't you know the file extension?

Comment: If you're literally at the command prompt (rather than a batch file) you can just press TAB.

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm developing an application to convert the natural human orders to do MS-DOS commands.
Most people don't use the extension when they want to play or read a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure only one file has that filename you use a for loop to search for the file like this:

```
FOR %A IN ("C:\path\to\directory\filename.*") DO start %A
```

In your example it would be:

```
FOR %A IN ("C:\AI\Bernard.*") DO start %A
```

You can put it in a batch-script:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN ("%~1.*") DO start %%A
```

and give the path to the filename without extension as argument (don't forget the surrounding double quotes).

If multiple files have that filename it will open them all.

Answer (score 0):

On linux terminal you could do something like this `vlc Bernard.*`,maybe you could try the `*` extension for windows.